# Laravel Eloquent Calculate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a Model and want to insert something into the database.

One of the fields should add a number to the current value (timestamp)

```
$purchases = new PurchasesModel($this->connection);
$purchases->updates_until = 'updates_until + ' . $updates_included_time;
```

This does of course not work, so how can i do that?

The `updates_until` field is formatted as timestamp (but since mysql 4.1 handled as datetime) in the database, `$updates_included_time` is a int value which should be added to the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `increments` method:

```
PurchasesModel::where('id', '=', 1)
              ->increment('updates_until', 'INTERVAL ' . $updates_included_time . ' SECOND');
```

You may change `SECOND` to `MINUTE`, or whatever suits you better.

Comment: Sorry if i am a bit dump but i tried: `$purchases->updates_until->increment('INTERVAL ' . $updates_included_time . ' SECOND');` but that seems not to work

Comment: No no, it was my fault actually. Forgot the first parameter. The `updates_until` part goes as the first parameter of the `increment` method.

Comment: Hmm still '0000-00-00 00:00:00' :/

Comment: Checkout the query produced: `dd(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: Ah sry edited the wrong file. Well i get an exception: `Call to a member function increment() on a non-object `. I guess it is cause i don't call the model static :/. Or not? It is obviously a object.

Comment: Are you trying to do this exactly as the code you posted on the question? Because if you are, it doesn't make much sense. You're actually creating a new, fresh record, and expecting a value to already be there, for the `updates_until` column.

Comment: I have set a default value for this field. Does that not work? If not, how can i just set it to the `$updates_included_time` then? Mysql won't accept a int like that anymore.

Comment: You'll have to work with a `DateTime` object, which, depending on what that `$updates_included_time` value represents, might work in different ways. If it's a Unix timestamp value, for instance, you'd do it like this: `$purcashes->updates_until = new DateTime('@' . $updates_included_time);`. The @ is what identifies it as a timestamp.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just thought there is a way to let mysql do that :)